# htmlService - Is response time slow?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have followed the hello world example for google apps script htmlService and I find the minimal script and html page takes seconds to respond. Is this to be expected???

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('helloPage.html');
}
```

Using Speed Tracer, I am seeing request timings of ~1sec for caja.js; 0.5 sec for jsapi; 0.75 sec for script.google.com/macros/static/client/css/4255899750-MaestroHtmlAppWrapperCss_ltr.css?

where should I look for a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are aware that this is slower than desired and are working hard to speed it up.

Comment: Thanks, I will leave it to you and stop looking for what I did wrong :)